# Spring MVC, Hibernate, MySQL output tables,charts

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, charts

I have a project that includes Spring MVC, Hibernate, MySQL.

I need:

1. Display the data from the tables in MySQL.
2. Output the statistics in the charts from MySQL.

What to use for these tasks?

Comment: I do not want a solution (solved code). I ask you to prompt in what direction to move.

Comment: Thank you for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to display data from DB,Kindly follow these steps

**Controller.java**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getData", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public List<User> getData(HttpSession session) {
    List<User> userList = userService.getData();
    return userList;
}
```

**Service.java**

```
public List<User> getData() {
    return this.userDAO.getData();
}
```

**UserDAO.java**

```
 public List<User> getData() {
        Session session = getSession();
        List<User> userList = session.createQuery(" query to fetch from DB").list();
        System.out.println(userList);
        return userList;
    }
```

This is a sample code.Which might help you.
If you struck anywhere can let us know

Happy coding...!!!